# Renew TTL of a node in Zookeeper

Tags: apache-zookeeper, ttl

I am keeping some configuration on Zookeeper which a what to expire after some time if it has not being updated.

By using TTL, I can achieve that, but how do I renew the TTL? remove and add node is an option but produce inconsistent states.

Would setData(same data) or Op.check renew the TTL of the node?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`setData` will renew the TTL of the node.**
Actually, not renew the ttl, but renew the mtime of the node. In Zookeeper, the way to check if a node should expire is to compare the return of `getElapsed` and configured `TTL`. `setData` will renew the mtime.

```
protected long getElapsed(DataNode node) {
    return Time.currentWallTime() - node.stat.getMtime();
}
```

Comment: mmmm but I have a client which continuously read this nodes and the expire after the configured TTL...

Comment: @DLanza what client driver do you use ? by 'TTL', do you mean the session timeout ?

Comment: Nop, I mean TTL nodes: https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.5.3-beta/zookeeperProgrammers.html#TTL+Nodes

Comment: @DLanza sorry i didn't know the new feature. after looking into the source, setData can meet your demand.